# Acer Aspire X1935 crashing

Tags: motherboard, crash, hardware-failure, acer-aspire

I have a 2.5 year old Acer Aspire X1935 desktop (i5-3450 3.10GHz x 4, 8GB RAM, ivybridge integrated graphics) that has been intermittently crashing. The crashes manifest as horizontal bars across the screen and no response to any input. This occurs in Windows 7, Ubuntu 14.04 and even the grub bootloader.

Memtest suggests the memory is OK. The computer is not running hot. Once it crashes, restarting the computer by turning off the power at the wall (the only option as nothing else works) straight away often results in another crash. Leaving the machine off for a period of an hour or more sometimes results in a crash but can also boot into a stable system.

Does this sound like the motherboard needs replacing?

Comment: Sounds like a video problem, if it has a pci video card slot,  i suggest trying a different video card.

Comment: It could also be simply a loose connector (or a connector that has a bit of corrosion). You might try reseating all connectors you can reach.